# Retrieve best number of clusters from NbClust

Tags: r, console, console-output

Many functions in R provide some sort of console output (such as NbClust() etc.) Is there any way of retrieving some of the output (e.g. a certain integer value) without having a look at the output? Any way of reading from the console?

Imagine the output would look like the following output from example code provided in the [package manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NbClust/NbClust.pdf):

```
[1] "Frey index : No clustering structure in this data set"
*** : The Hubert index is a graphical method of determining the number of clusters.
                In the plot of Hubert index, we seek a significant knee that corresponds to a 
                significant increase of the value of the measure i.e the significant peak in Hubert
                index second differences plot. 

*** : The D index is a graphical method of determining the number of clusters. 
                In the plot of D index, we seek a significant knee (the significant peak in Dindex
                second differences plot) that corresponds to a significant increase of the value of
                the measure. 

******************************************************************* 
* Among all indices:                                                
* 1 proposed 2 as the best number of clusters 
* 2 proposed 4 as the best number of clusters 
* 2 proposed 6 as the best number of clusters 
* 1 proposed 7 as the best number of clusters 

                   ***** Conclusion *****                            

* According to the majority rule, the best number of clusters is  4 


*******************************************************************
```

How would I retrieve the value **4** from the last line of the above output?

Comment: NO, `x$Best.nc` returns a list containing for each index its respective "number of clusters"-value. But this is not what I am interested in, I want to retrieve the value in the last line...

Comment: @zx8754 As written above, I am really looking for a way of retrieving information from console output, not only for `NbClust()` but in general for any output generated by functions in R

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you @zx8754

Thank you for also pointing out that working with console output is not so usual, do you want to make this the answer for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to work with objects rather than output in the console. Any *"good"* function would return hopefully structured output that can be accessed using `$` or `@` signs, use `str()` to see object's structure.

In your case, I think this should work:

```
length(unique(res$Best.partition))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```
max(unlist(res[4]))
```